# Write a function that will return the two number array combination with value summed at 5. I can't get all the opportunities

Tags: javascript

A job posting wants me to write a an answer to a question which if I solve I am eligible for the next rownd.

> Write a function that will return the array combination with value
>   summed at 5. Important: Use only one "for" loop. Example: var
>   rand_array = [1,3,5,2,4,6]; var target_sum = 5; Output = [1,4], [5],
>   [3,2], [2,3], [4,1];

I attempted to find a solution online and stumbled upon this:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-a-and-a-number-x-check-for-pair-in-a-with-sum-as-x/ as StackOverflow wants you to do your own research first.

However, when trying to convert it to JS, all that happened was that it returned just one case where it worked. I need it to return every case where it worked. I then make some other changes and it just stopped working now.

```
var ra = [1,3,5,2,4,6];
var target = 5


ra.sort();
lower = 0;
higher = ra.length -1;

var solutions = [];
var result;

while (lower < higher) {
        if (ra[lower] + ra[higher] === target){
            result = [ra[lower], ra[higher]];
            solutions.push(result);
        }
        else if (ra[lower] + ra[higher] > target){
            higher--;
        }
        else {
            lower++; 
        }
    }

    return solutions;
}

console.log(solutions);
```

Can someone write an example for me?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work at all at the moment because it doesn't always increment `lower` or `higher` (resulting in an infinite loop). It also has greater complexity than necessary (`.sort` has complexity `O(n log n)`), but the instructions indicate that low complexity is important. The array also isn't being sorted numerically. (To sort numerically, use `.sort((a, b) => a - b)`)

If you want a solution with the least complexity possible, `O(n)`, while iterating, create an object. On every iteration, check to see if the object has a key for which the current number would sum with to 5 (eg, when iterating on `1`, look to see if a `4` property exists on the object). If one is found, add it to the solutions. Otherwise, set a new key on the object:

```js
const ra = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6];
const target = 5;
const solutions = [];
const obj = {};
for (const item of ra) {
  const match = target - item;
  if (obj[match]) {
    solutions.push([item, match]);
    delete obj[match];
  } else {
    obj[item] = true;
  }
}
console.log(solutions);
```

If there may be repeated numbers, then store a count in the object instead of just `true`:

```js
const ra = [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4];
const target = 5;
const solutions = [];
const obj = {};
for (const item of ra) {
  const match = target - item;
  if (obj[match]) {
    solutions.push([item, match]);
    obj[match]--;
  } else {
    obj[item] = (obj[item] || 0) + 1;
  }
}
console.log(solutions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to write the actual answer because its a job assignment, but I will say that a simple 2 loop function is the obvies solution, than try to think not checking the array from the top and the bottum, rether like the formation of a loop in a loop.

hint :

```
let i = 0;
let j = 0;

while (i < arr.langth) {
    ...
    if (j < arr.langth) {
        j++;
    } else {
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it stands just does not work at all. CertainPerformance has a solid answer, except that it doesn't do the task as required, i.e. treat the same numbers in a different order as different or get the values which are equal to target as solutions. Here is my solution to your problem:

```js
const ra = [1,3,5,2,4,6];
const target = 5

function getSumsOfTarget(ra, target){
 ra.sort();
 lower = 0;
 higher = ra.length -1;
 
 const solutions = [];
 let result;
 
 while (lower < ra.length && higher >= 0) {
  const sum = ra[lower] + ra[higher];
  if (ra[lower] === target) {
   result = [ra[lower]];
   solutions.push(result);
   break;
  }
  if (sum === target){
   result = [ra[lower], ra[higher]];
   solutions.push(result);
   lower++; 
  }
  else if (sum > target){
   higher--;
  }
  else {
   lower++; 
  }
 }
 
 return solutions;
}

console.log(getSumsOfTarget(ra, target));
```